# error while updating a database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
    $record_id1=$_REQUEST['record_id'];

    echo $record_id1;
    echo $dor1;
    if(isset($_REQUEST['updatebtn']))
    {                    
        $status=$_REQUEST['up'];
        $sql="UPDATE record SET dor='$dor1' WHERE record_id=$record_id1";
        mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    }
```

I am trying to update my `record` table which will take record_id1 in its `WHERE` clause and will simply update `dor=$dor` here `dor` is properly set in the page .The problem is when i try to execute this page i get the following error :

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax...

i have spent hours and was not able to point out the bug when i use `... WHERE record_id=7(any numeric value)` the table gets updated but when i am updating it with `$record_id1` i am getting the above error.

`Data Type
dor =String
record_id=int`

Comment: use mysqli_* functions. mysql_* functions not recommended

Comment: or try adding quotes around `$record_id1` in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: but dor's type is text so `'$dor1'` must be used...and @VotetoClose can you please show me one example to do this job

Comment: [Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ). **You are also wide open to [SQL injections](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174)**

Comment: Also, post the **whole** error message. You left off the usual part.

Comment: please add `var_dump($record_id1)` and post the result.

Comment: may be you have to add trim. $record_id1=trim($_REQUEST['record_id']);

Answer (score 1):

Is your table column name `record_id1` with a 1 on the end or just `record_id`. According to your question you can do a custom query using and numberical value assigning it to `record_id1` (with a 1 on the end).

If your column name has a 1 then you just need to update your query to match the correct name.

Answer (score 0):

You should be escaping your variables:

```
$sql = sprintf(
    "UPDATE record SET dor='%s' WHERE record_id=%s",
    mysql_real_escape_string($dor),
    mysql_real_escape_string($record_id1)
);
```

and echo your SQL to make sure what you're running is what you're expecting:

```
echo $sql;
```

Numeric values can have quotes around them as well, so this will work too:

```
$sql = sprintf(
    "UPDATE record SET dor='%s' WHERE record_id='%s'",
    mysql_real_escape_string($dor),
    mysql_real_escape_string($record_id1)
);
```

Now, all the mysql_* functions are deprecated so you should be using the mysqli_* equivalents.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql="UPDATE record SET dor='$dor1' WHERE record_id=$record_id1";
```

> The problem is when i try to execute this page i get the following
>   error :

-

> when i use ... WHERE record_id1=7(any numeric value) the table gets
>   updated

is that `1` after the record_id (column name) correct? is your column called `record_id` or `record_id1`? If its really `record_id1` you ofc. need to use:

```
 ... WHERE record_id1=$record_id1 ...
```

Comment: my column name is record_id

Comment: and i am storing the id which i am getting from some other page in record_id1

Comment: @rick then why "... WHERE record_id1=7"

Comment: @rick then please fix your description about the working manual query - that's confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you have an unwanted space character in your variable `$record_id1`.

Please use [**trim**()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php), if it so.

```
$record_id1=trim($_REQUEST['record_id']);
```

Query:

```
$sql="UPDATE `record` SET `dor`='$dor1' WHERE `record_id`='$record_id1'";
```

Answer (score -1):

Try putting qoutes around your WHERE clause, like this:

```
$sql="UPDATE record SET dor='$dor1' WHERE record_id='$record_id1'";
```

And just one more thing. Please use MySQLi or PDO and not MySQL. MySQL is deprecated. And using MySQLi or PDO allows you to do Prepared Statements

Comment: You dont know the content of `$dor1` or `$record_id1` - How can you decide whether quotes are needed or not? Trial-and-error-advice is not an answer.

Comment: @dognose Then see user583576's answer

Comment: Other worse answers wouldnt make yours better :)

Answer (score -1):

```
$sql="UPDATE record SET dor = '$dor1' WHERE record_id = '$record_id1'";
```